# Get the value using substr and instr in oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have following value in the table.

1. aaaaaa                 26G     2.0G      23G     8      tmp
2. tmpfs                 506M     0        506M     0     /dev/shm

I need to store  first value that is ('aaaaaa' and'tmpfs') and second value (26 and 506) in another table. I got first value by 
CAST(substr(COL_1,1,InStr(COL_1,' ')-1) AS VARCHAR2(10)) col

How do I get the second value such as 26 and 506 using substring and instring.?

Answer (score 0):

There is an optional argument to `instr` where you can specify the nth occurrence of a specific string being searched.

```
CAST(substr(COL_1,InStr(COL_1,' ',1,1)+1,InStr(COL_1,' ',1,2)-InStr(COL_1,' ',1,1)-1) AS VARCHAR2(10))
```

To only extract the number from this substring, use `regexp_substr`. This assumes letters always follow one or more numeric characters.

```
regexp_substr(CAST(substr(COL_1,InStr(COL_1,' ',1,1)+1,InStr(COL_1,' ',1,2)-InStr(COL_1,' ',1,1)-1) AS VARCHAR2(10)),'\d+')
```

Comment: It did not return anything, I need to get second value as 26 and 506 and so on....

Comment: i edited it after posting it first.try the latest version.

Comment: aaaaaa                 26G     2.0G     23G      8        tmp
   I need to get 26  from second  column. It is returning null with above solution you gave...

Comment: great it is working now but i do not want G and M letters , only numbers..

Comment: will you always have one letter?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(col1, '[^ ]+ ', 1, 1) as first,
       regexp_substr(col1, '[^ ]+ ', 1, 2) as second
```

This returns the value with a space at the end.  I think the pattern works without the space, because regular expression matching is greedy in Oracle:

```
select regexp_substr(col1, '[^ ]+', 1, 1) as first,
       regexp_substr(col1, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) as second
```

Comment: You can use replace, or you can use `substr()` or even `regexp_substr()` again.